# How to get the shipping method code by the rate_id in the Magento?

Tags: magento

How can I get the shipping method code when I have its `rate_id`.

I have the table `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` in which the shipping method code, code title and all other are defined. I just want to get the code. my `rate_id` is like `2163`.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple. Use the code below :

```
/*Shipping Rate ID*/
$rate_id = 2163;

/*Load the Shipping Rate Model by its ID*/
$salesQuoteRate = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address_rate')->load($rate_id);

if($salesQuoteRate){
   echo '<br/>CODE : '.$salesQuoteRate->getCode();
   echo '<br/>METHOD : '.$salesQuoteRate->getMethod();
}
```

Comment: BTW if this works, kindly accept the answer. So that its clear to anyone who gets to this thread some time later.

Comment: Outputing like CODE :
METHOD :

Comment: Thanks man. i was searching from the wrong database. Thanks it works